# Query get data from table according to another one

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables in MySQL database one for orders:

[image: orders table]

And I have another table called users:

[image: users table]

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE project_id=12
```

I want to get all data from orders table but replace added_by column value with first name from users table and edit_done_by value with first name from users table also.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing two `join`s:

```
select u.id, u.project_id, o1.name added_by, o2.name edit_done_by, u.date_created
from users u 
inner join orders o1 on o1.id = u.added_by     and o1.project_id = u.project_id
inner join orders o2 on o2.id = u.edit_done_by and o2.project_id = u.project_id
where u.project_id = 12
```

I had to an assumption on the relation between the tables, that they relate through the `project_id` as well.